# php / Gerenciador de Conteúdo

Tags: php, javascript

Alguém ai sabe onde posso achar um gerenciador de conteúdo simples ou
por onde eu começo a fazer um bem simples?

Comment: usa o wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode começar com o mais utilizado que é o Wordpress, para o gerenciamento de conteudo:

[Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:P%C3%A1gina_Inicial)

Alem dele tem outros free, e cada um com suas particularidades:

[Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/)

[Concrete5](https://www.concrete5.org/)

[Drupal](http://www.drupal.org.br/)

Cabe a você agora escolher qual o melhor de acordo com suas necessidades